# Unable to load class 'com.google.gwt.validation.rebind.GwtSpecificValidatorGenerator'

Tags: java, gwt

What could be the reason for following error, guys ?

```
Loading inherited module 'com.test.courierApp.AdminPanel'
   Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
      Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.editor.Editor'
         Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.validation.Validation'
            [ERROR] Unable to load class 'com.google.gwt.validation.rebind.GwtSpecificValidatorGenerator'
```

It started happening after I switched from GWT which I built myself to official 2.5. I can see that GwtSpecificValidatorGenerator [existed in trunk](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/validation/rebind/GwtSpecificValidatorGenerator.java?r=11210) before and that explains why compiler can't find it.

But what I can't explain is what references this missing class in my code. I searched everywhere, even in IntelliJ's cache...

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was some IDEA's glitch. After deleting all Global Libraries and re-adding necessary ones compilation error went away. Too bad :(